# No effect of controlling external usb soundbar with Alsamixer (i3wm)

Tags: sound, alsa, indicator-sound, i3-wm

I have a Dell monitor with an accompanying USB soundbar. On Gnome it used to work. Using alsamixed to switch nothing happens when I change the volume. Sound output remains the same (i.e laptop speaker or headphones).

I did a quick search on this but didn't find anything relevant.

Why & how can I make it work? And is there an easy way to make the switch between the default and the external sound bar?

Comment: `alsamixer` does not control which sound device is used. You're probably using PulseAudio; try `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Is it possible to make the volume control knobs on the soundboard work in i3?